# 502 Bad Gateway errors when I try to enable php in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I've been trying to get php scripts running on my Ubuntu 12.04/nginx server.  I know the 12.04 is out of date, but I'm stuck there.

I have seen a tremendous amount of different configurations for the nginx/sites-available file.  I've tried a lot of them.  I've also tried switching php to listening to a different port (I randomly picked 8889 and 9001), which i set both in that file and in etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.

I want to note that when I apt-get install php5-fpm, I notice this warning:
update-rc.d: warning: php5-fpm stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (none)

However it doesn't seem to suggest that fpm has failed and there is further (non-warning/error output below that line in the install output).

I also want to mention that this server also runs python django environment on a different virtual host which also listens to port 9000, but I think that doesn't matter because they are both nginx processes?  And, like I mentioned, I tried changing the port for php but it did not solve the problem.

The only thing the script does that I'm trying to run is print hello world, so there should be no problems there.

This is my nginx/sites-available/myvirtualhost config file (you can see my many different php configs commented out - the top one was from my sites-available/default file (commented out there and default has no link in sites-enabled):

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
#
        server_name mag.somedomain.com;
#
        root /var/www/mag.somedomain.com/public_html;
        index index.html;
#
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php5-cgi alone:
        #        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #}
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       fastcgi_index index.php;
        #       include fastcgi_params;
        #}
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mag.somedomain.com/public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

When I look in nginx/error.log (when the port is set to 9000):

```
2016/05/27 17:16:14 [error] 10689#0: *150 upstream sent unsupported FastCGI protocol version: 72 while reading response header from upstream, client: 99.3.19.77, server: mag.somedomain.com, request: "GET /version.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mag.somedomain.com"
```

If I change the port, I get a blank webpage (instead of 502) and nothing in the error log.

When I use netstat to see what's listening i get (there are some other ports being listened to as well):

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8801          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26768/python    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8802          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8444/python     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10686/nginx -g daem
```

Anyone know what I need to do?  I've been beating on this for hours.

Comment: If I'm not misinterpreting, your nginx is listening on that port? What does your php-fpm config say for the pool you're trying to proxy to? Are you sure 100% it's listening on the port 9000? `sudo lsof -i :9000` and if it doesn't say `php-fpm` then you're proxying from nginx to nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out it really was the 9000 port.  I guess the two alternate ports I tried were not okay to use (8999 and 9001).  When I checked the php5-fpm error log it said that port 9000 was already in use.  So I picked yet another random port - this time 8070 - and my hello world script magically worked.  Go figure.